# can't send password to ftp server

Tags: windows, emacs, ftp, tramp, emacsw32

i have running filezilla ftp server on my windows 7

i have running emacs w32 client (GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1)

my ~/.emacs config file contains:

```
M-x (setq ange-ftp-ftp-program-name "C:/cygwin/bin/ftp.exe") ;;http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp -> ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/windows/contrib/ftp-for-win32.zip
M-x (setq tramp-default-method "ftp")
```

but i cannot connect to my localhost, but

```
explorer ftp://mycustomlogin:mycustonpassword@localhost
```

works fine and shows the folder content, so the ftp server is doing well.

If I try to exec

```
M-x load-file RET /mycustomlogin@localhost:/index.php
```

it prompts me for login. on the filezilla log i see that login was accepted, then i am asked for password for ftp.exe in minibuffer and, then, again in the ftp-connection buffer.

*the problem is that i can not connect to ftp server from windows*, the whole procedure, done on linux ubuntu goes very well. 
did anyone try to do so on emacsw32 and worked for him/her?

there is a screen of the problem 
[image: emacs ftp screen]